# Not getting external Json API response using RestTemplate

Tags: json, spring-boot, resttemplate

Getting External API As below image-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a28Y1.png

```
{
"status" : 200,
"data" : [ 
{
"_id": "StringValue1",
"itmId": "StringValue1",
"itmName": "StringValue1",
"imgFileName":"StringValue1",
"imgFile":"byte[] data"
},
{
"_id": "StringValue2",
"itmId": "StringValue2",
"itemName": "StringValue2",
"imgFileName":"StringValue2",
"imageFile":"byte[] data2"
}
],
"message":""
}
```

Used as data array object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {     
public String status;
Data [] data;
public String message
}
```

Another Object is below

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Data{              
public String _id;
public String itmid;
public String itmName;
public String imgFileName;
byte [] imgFile;
}
```

Used /getForObject/exchange/getForEntity but not getting any response. Pls check at bottom method I used.

Now used as List of Data Object also not getting any response-

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {     
public String status;
List<Data> data;
public String message
}


@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Data{              
public String _id;
public String itmid;
public String itmName;
public String imgFileName;
byte [] imgFile;
}
```

Here how called these by resttemplate-

1. Response obj=restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Response.class,"paramvalue");
2. ResponseEntity obj=restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET,null,Response.class,"paramvalue");
3. ResponseEntity obj=restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Response.class,"paramvalue");

Tried all the possible ways, but not getting any response from external rest API.

Please note response json conatin data[] where we have byte data for image.
Need support and help pls..

Can any one support on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried but I am getting only object ref response as Response@5ffead27 if I call -             ResponseEntity<Response> obj=template.getForEntity(uri,Response.class,"param")

Comment: Either Data[] obj or List<Data> obj, if I make change and call resttemplate all the scenarios I am not getting response, not sure why?

Comment: Please find my answer below and let me know it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking by following:

```
ResponseEntity<List<Data>> responseEntity = 
  restTemplate.exchange(
    BASE_URL,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    null,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Data>>() {}
  );
List<Data> data = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: Many thnx for your support & help, but my Data object is inside Response Object. As, Response Object is holding two parameter- status & message. Again thnx in advance.

Comment: Is `Response` a custom object or normal http response object? If its normal http response object then you can access the status via  `responseEntity.getStatus()`

Comment: Response object is CustomObject that holds few additional fields along with Data object. Also Data object contain a field called byte [].

Comment: Could you try my answer once  to ensure the response type and then you can also try below:
`ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Response.class);`

Comment: Many Thanks Felix for giving your valuable time.. if I called like below I am getting  response only object ref@1fa268de                                                                                                                     ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Response.class,"paramvalue");                                                                                    response.getBody();                                                                                                        I tried this method also.

Comment: Did you try `ResponseEntity<List<Data>> responseEntity = 
  restTemplate.exchange(
    BASE_URL,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    null,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Data>>() {}
  );
List<Data> data = responseEntity.getBody();` also?

Sorry I don't follow the above comment. Did you mean it worked or it doesn't.

Comment: I tried but result is same. Not getting response.